# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

I’m trying to calculate all EditText numbers and get the sum and I’m using `DecimalFormat` to get the sum in € form. I get a crash every time. Can anybody help me pls?

```
    //Total
            DecimalFormat dfpdf = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String finalPricepdf1 = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Preis1.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis2.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis3.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis4.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis5.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis6.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis7.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis8.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis9.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis10.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis11.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis12.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis13.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis14.getText().toString()) 
                + Double.parseDouble(Preis15.getText().toString())
            );

            if (Bar.isChecked())
                addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "BAR",  dfpdf.format(finalPricepdf1) + "€", mOrderAcNameFont, mOrderAcNameFont);
            else if (Karte.isChecked())
                addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "KARTE", finalPricepdf1 + "€", mOrderAcNameFont, mOrderAcNameFont);
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.bestellungsdrucker, PID: 13502
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Comment: To debug further you will need to find out what the string value is you are parsing. It may be that there are other characters that are in the sting that are confusing it, such as currency or decimal points.

Comment: im usingen decimal points

Comment: As in dots or commas?

Comment: @nylanderdev  Im usingen it as in dots

Comment: Which exact string value are you handing to it?